# django SQL Console

Tags: django

I am trying to debug a piece of SQL that is coming back incorrectly. I am not sure if django or mysql is handling it wrong so I want to run it through a django console.

Is there a way to set this up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is to install the [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) in your project.  It provides an unobtrusive interface that gives you access to the SQL queries so you can hunt down what's happening at that level.

Answer (score 14):

`manage.py dbshell` or `manage.py shell` shell being going into the python interpreter loading your project settings, dbshell putting you in the database cli client.  django.db.queries holds the queries that django creates.  bigmattyh's suggestion of debug toolbar is a good one, but not interactive.